# Error in right and bottom border to imageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have a ImageView and I want to set a rounded border, I have it with a drawable shape but at the right and bottom, the border its not correct, I set a screenshot for understand this:

[image]

This is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_message"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_bt_s"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rl_bt_s"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send_bt_c"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_bt_c"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"                
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_bt_s"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/et_message"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_chat_s"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="false"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_action_attach"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/bt_chat_s"
                android:layout_alignStart="@id/bt_chat_s"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_input_plus"
                android:background="@drawable/chat_attachment_border_smsmode"/>
    </RelativeLayout>    
</merge>
```

And this is the shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#999999"
            />
    <padding android:left="4dp"
             android:top="4dp"
             android:right="4dp"
             android:bottom="4dp"
            />
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

As you can see in the screenshot, the right border and bottom border its not completely but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parent RelativeLayout to have the width you desire and have the child views match_parent for their width/height.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_bt_s"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/et_message"
        android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_chat_s"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"/>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_action_attach"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_input_plus"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_attachment_border_smsmode"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```